# Can jenkins while build download *.mo from transifex?

Tags: jenkins, translation

I'm using Zend/Translator and gettext, and while jenkins build is running can it update MO files from my transifex account?

Comment: How come you aren't checking the translations into your repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra step in the build process for that.

First, you need to use the [transifex client](http://help.transifex.com/features/client/) and set it up for
your project. Many projects choose to have the .tx/config file that is
required inside the repository itself. See for instance
https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/.tx/

Given that, you can configure your project to first pull all PO files
from Transifex with `tx pull -a` and then run the `msgfmt` command to
generate the MO files from the PO files.